# Facebook user login: user authentication without app authorization

Tags: php, facebook

I have a problem with the Facebook login. Currently I'm using login url (getLoginUrl( $params=array())), which automatically takes care of the user authentication and app authentication / authorization.

This means, that when the new user opens application, FB automatically redirects him to the authentication page.

In such cases, I would rather receive information, that this user has not yet authenticated my app. This would give me a chance to show new users some additional information about the app, before they face the FB authentication page.

I guess that I'm looking for a function, which would return, whether the current user has already authenticated my app or not.

Is there a way to retrieve this kind of information form FB?

Comment: Are you currently redirecting automatically with header() or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you currently redirecting automatically with header() or something? Something like this maybe helps?

```
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user) {
  //stuff when user authenticated
} else {
  //stuff when user is not authenticated
  ?>
  <a href="<?php echo $facebook->getLoginUrl(array()); ?>">authenticate</a>
  <?php
}
```

Also thumbs up whit this approach- I think it's more user friendlier to not redirect automatically before showing user what your app promises. Maybe my demo app helps also? http://eagerfish.eu/example-facebook-iframe-app-using-graph-api-through-php-sdk/

Comment: Is there a way, to redirect a user to the Facebook login page with a different link  than the one, returned by the "getLoginUrl" function? In case the user is not logged in to FB, this url automatically performs the authorisation. I would just like the user to login and reload the app. Is this possible?